# Could redisTemplate.executePipelined cause SocketTimeOut

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

This is my code :

```
redisTemplate.executePipelined(new SessionCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object execute(RedisOperations redisOperations) throws DataAccessException {
        redisTemplate.opsForSet().add(e, businessCode);
        return null;
    }
});
```

inner code “redisTemplate.opsForSet().add(e, businessCode);” is using the one **connection**？

Thanks for answer

supplement stack error info：

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.zRange(JedisConnection.java:2348)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.zRange(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations$5.doInRedis(DefaultZSetOperations.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations$5.doInRedis(DefaultZSetOperations.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations.range(DefaultZSetOperations.java:98)
    at com.*.mshop.reach.service.impl.ReachServiceImpl.query(ReachServiceImpl.java:178)
    at com.*.mshop.reach.service.impl.ReachServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$633d23e1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
    at com.*.mshop.reach.service.impl.ReachServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$486aa953.query(<generated>)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.query$original$1525E0bP(ReachControllerImpl.java:174)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.query$original$1525E0bP$accessor$dcQnJrPQ(ReachControllerImpl.java)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl$auxiliary$jZ0njKo2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.InstMethodsInter.intercept(InstMethodsInter.java:86)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.query(ReachControllerImpl.java)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.queryCommodity$original$1525E0bP(ReachControllerImpl.java:203)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.queryCommodity$original$1525E0bP$accessor$dcQnJrPQ(ReachControllerImpl.java)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl$auxiliary$NkOmWqfY.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.InstMethodsInter.intercept(InstMethodsInter.java:86)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl.queryCommodity(ReachControllerImpl.java)
    at com.*.mshop.facade.controller.ReachControllerImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8f1c1b6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

before this exception called executePipelined  , about 1 minutes , cound not get redis connection .

redis connection pool config :

```
spring.redis.pool.max-active = 2000
spring.redis.pool.max-wait = 5000
spring.redis.pool.max-idle = 200
spring.redis.pool.min-idle = 10
spring.redis.timeout = 0
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking about. Are you asking about a SocketTimeOut exception or whether your redisTemplate is using a connection pool?

Comment: is SocketTimeOut exception , my redis connection pool config is : spring.redis.pool.max-active = 2000
spring.redis.pool.max-wait = 5000
spring.redis.pool.max-idle = 200
spring.redis.pool.min-idle = 10
spring.redis.timeout = 0

Comment: Still, what exacly is the question exactly? With that configuration I expect that a connection pool is active, but it starts with no connections. So the first time you try and do something, it tries to connect and that can cause a connection timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis Pipeline have different implement for Jedis and Lettuce.

In Jedis, pipeline will block 1 connection and send all pipeline commands together with same connection(bio)

In Lettuce, pipeline use Netty nio as network connection tool. So during the pipeline execute in client side, it will not block the connection(generally lettuce will use single connection). And when pipeline execute(send to Redis), it will select 1 connection from Netty.

And both libraries are using same connection for pipeline commands as they will send all commands together in a single network request.

Comment: so maybe  create to many pipeline cause block , i do create multiple pipelines in my code。  is this pipelines is delay send ?  my log show me the confirm is one minutes ago. socketTimeOut It happened after 1 minute

Comment: It will send to RedisClient immediately after you sync pipeline. But if connection pool is full(Jedis use block io, which block the connection for each command), it will wait until next available connection.